# How is 1.0 / 3.0 not an undefined operation in C++? (not representable in float)

Tags: c++, floating-point, language-lawyer, c++20

The C++ standard says:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.

and

> The binary / operator yields the quotient from the division of the first expression by the second. If the quotient a/b is representable in the type of the result [snip]; otherwise, the behavior of a/b is undefined.

If I have:

```
double x = 1.0 / 3.0;
```

The result of the division of 1 by 3 is the real number "one third".  One third is not representable in the type of the result (`double`, usually the IEEE754 double-precision binary64 floating point type).

Does that mean that the above statement is an undefined operation?  Surely it cannot be - but I don't understand how it isn't?

Comment: Range here means `FLOATING_POINT_TYPE_MIN_VAL <= value <= FLOATING_POINT_TYPE_MAX_VAL`, not being exactly representable in the number of bits the type has.

Comment: how do you represent it in decimal?  0.3?  0.333? 0.3333333?  same problem with base 2 (or many other bases).

Comment: `double` != real number. Some operation can be perfectly well define in terms of arithmetic operations on a C++ type, even though the result does not match the math on real numbers exactly. An even simpler example would be doing the same for `int`s (C++ expression `1/3`); the result is `0` which is clearly different to the real number "one third"; It's just that the  C++ specification requires the expression to be treated differently to the operations on real numbers...

Comment: The mathematical value "one third" is between two values that a `double` can represent and the result of the expression `1.0/3.0` is one of those two values.   Which value is picked is unspecified, not undefined (there is a finite number of possibilities, and an implementation is permitted to choose any of them) by the C++ standard.  For IEEE floating point, the choice of those two values is determined by "rounding mode".  Other floating point specifications may pick the closest, always round toward zero, or always round away from zero.

Comment: @old_timer: It could be reasonably stated that the real number one third is not representable in decimal.  I think it's a bit of stretch to take the C++ standards use of the term "representable" as some sort of vague "approximately representable" meaning without a clarification or a definition.

Comment: it is not representable, has nothing to do with exceptions, they are just giving out additional advice about base 2 just like we already know things from grade school about base 10 (repetitive values or patterns to the right of the decimal point, same deal with floating point formats.)  A comment on elementary math, has nothing to do with exceptions or faults or the floating point format used, etc.   Most math fixed or float cannot be represented in the language or the formats so there is no way that that is a fault.  One big company didnt even fault on divide by zero (fixed point).

Comment: a fixed length mantissa is at the core of floating point

Comment: @old_timer: It isn't a duplicate.  See here for the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76503833/1131467

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out the interpretation was incorrect and based on a misreading of the full text of the quoted sequence:

[expr.mul]p4:

> For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded; if the quotient a/b is representable in the type of the result, (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a; otherwise, the behavior of both a/b and a%b is undefined.

https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#4

The entire quoted sequence only applies to *integral* operands.
In particular, the term "representable in the type" is only used in the context of integral operands and not floating-point operands.

Floating-point types have no "range of representable values" defined in the standard, nor is such a concept used in the standard.

Comment: What about https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#pre-4?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: What about it?  That only applies to integral types., I think. The range of representable values of integral types is defined in [basic.fundamental]p1 and p2.  There is no definition of range of representable values given for floating-point types.

Comment: It doesn't explicitly limit itself to integral types. *"There is no definition of range of representable values given for floating-point types"* Sounds like an editoral error to me, I doubt the intent was to implicitly limit this to integers based on such a minute detail. The explanation by @Kaz makes more sense to me. (but I didn't downvote)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I agree, but the "range of representable values" for floating-point types is not defined, so I'm not sure what else to make of [expr.pre]p4 other than adding an implicit "if the type has a representable range of values then".  If the range of representable values of floating-points were defined, I would expect them to be defined in [basic.fundamental]p12.

Comment: "but the "range of representable values" for floating-point types is not defined" It is defined by the semantics of `<numeric_limits>`, specifically it is precisely `[numeric_limits<T>::lowest() ..  numeric_limits<T>::max()]`

Answer (score 6):

The word "range" here refers to being in between the lowest and highest representable value. It's not the mathematical term as in "domain" and "range".

Real values can be out of range of a floating-point type due to being too large (far away from zero) or too small (nonzero values too close to zero).

Floating point types are inexact; that is in their nature. Some calculations produce a value which is an approximation to the exact real value. If such calculations produced garbage results or exceptions, floating-point would not meet its purpose.

Comment: "or too small" that's never out of range.

Comment: @n.m.: `-1e500` is out of range of most floating point hardware because it's too small.

Comment: All finite floating point values are _exact_.  It is the operations that do not yield the exact mathematical result.

Comment: @JerryCoffin  To me "small" always means "close to zero", never "far left from zero".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Whether floating-point values are exact or not depends on what they represent; we can't tell just by looking at them. Of course each one is nominally some rational number. But that rational number may represent a range of real numbers. Or it could just be itself. You can't tell by looking at it.  A floating-point value could actually be a really bad approximation; e.g. 0.125 is exactly 1/8 in one very real sense (pardon the pun),but it could be a rounded off r measurement providing 3 significant figures, representing anything from 0.1245.. to 0.1254...

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit We should adopt the word "deeper" for more negative. 1 is deeper than 4, -5 is deeper than -2. :)

Comment: @Kaz: Re “Whether floating-point values are exact or not depends on what they represent; we can't tell just by looking at them.”: The IEEE-754 specification is clear: Each floating-point datum that is not a NaN or infinity represents one specific number exactly. It does not represent a range or interval. If a programmer writes code to treat a floating-point number as an interval, that is a feature of their program, not of floating-point numbers or floating-point arithmetic. One could do the same with an integer type, but we do not consider values of integer types to represent intervals.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The IEEE-754 specification didn't invent floating-point numbers, so it doesn't get to dictate that to us. Say we have an A and B which are rationals exactly represented in floating-point. We divide C = A/B.   In that situation if A/B is not representable,the floating point system chooses, as the result, some D which is very close to C. That D obviously represents the true result C.  The idea of numbers representing other nearby numbers is baked into the floating-point concept, and has been before there was IEEE 754.

Comment: @Kaz: Re “That D obviously represents the true result C”: No, that is not obvious, and it is false. With integers, the integer system chooses 2 as the result of 7/3, but that does not mean 2 represents 7/3. There is no basis for such a conclusion. Re “the floating point system chooses, as the result, some D which is very close to C”: Yes, it chooses some result to deliver. That does not mean the result represents A/B. The model used in IEEE-754 is the same in this regard as the model used in C, C++, textbooks, and academic papers. It is how proofs about floating-point arithmetic are done.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Represents means something like "stands for'. For instance your `M_PI` constant represents π.  When engineering and scientific formulas that contain π are translated to floating-point code, the `M_PI` constant or equivalent is used. It represents π.

Comment: @Kaz: That is not the model used in IEEE 754, the C standard, the C++ standard, floating-point textbooks, or academic papers on floating-point. Working with floating-point arithmetic correctly sometimes requires analysis and proof. Trying to analyze floating-point software or write proofs using “represents” in such a crude way will not work. It is not engineering. We have too many problems with people not understanding floating-point code, so it is important to convey the model correctly. Floating-point behavior becomes clearer when the model is understood.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mistaking "can't be represented" for "can't be represented perfectly".

At least with typical hardware, if I do something like:

```cpp
double x = 1e300 / 1e-300;
```

The resulting value (1e600) is outside the range that can be represented (at all) so the result is undefined.

Something like `1.0 / 3.0` can't be represented *exactly*, but can be represented to some specified level of precision. And, of course, if somebody really wanted to, they could build base-3 floating point hardware that could represent `1.0/3.0` perfectly (but lose the ability to represent `1.0/2.0` perfectly, of course).

Looking at it from a slightly different direction, it largely comes down to the underlying hardware. Typically, you have IEEE 754 (or some variant of it). This standard defines the "correct" result (to the bit level) for something like `1.0/3.0` on binary hardware. Even though that is *not* exactly one third, it is what's defined as the "correct" result. As such, as long as the result you get is what IEEE 754 specifies, it's representing the correct result, even though that's different from what you'd expect in the realm of math on real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean that the above statement is an undefined operation?

`1.0/3.0` is OK.

When an math operator like `/` cannot return the *exact* mathematical result as a floating point value, the value returned is one of the two nearest representable floating point values, one larger, one smaller.  That is *rounding* and the selection depends on rounding mode.

Of course with a *domain* problem, like `x/0.0`, even the math result is not defined.

Should there not exist two representable floating point values that bound the math result, that is when trouble occurs - leading to UB.

Often with *infinity*, there is always 2 bounding values.